# Cannot find symbol error in action listener

Tags: java, compiler-errors, actionlistener

For our final project in our computer math class, we have to make a game, my group is doing tic tac toe

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class Driver extends JFrame 
{

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
Driver gst = new Driver();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
 frame.setSize(1280, 720);
 frame.setLocation(200, 100);


gst.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
gst.pack();
gst.setVisible(true);
  }

  public Driver() 
  {
Container pane = getContentPane();
pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

////////Buttons////////
//1,1
JButton oneOnebutton = new JButton();
pane.add(oneOnebutton);
oneOnebutton.addActionListener(new oneOneListener());
oneOnebutton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

//1,2
JButton oneTwobutton = new JButton();
pane.add(oneTwobutton);
oneTwobutton.addActionListener(new oneTwoListener());
oneTwobutton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

//1,3
JButton oneThreebutton = new JButton();
pane.add(oneThreebutton);
oneThreebutton.addActionListener(new oneThreeListener());
oneThreebutton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

//2,1
   JButton twoOnebutton = new JButton();
   pane.add(twoOnebutton);
   twoOnebutton.addActionListener(new twoOneListener());
   twoOnebutton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

//2,2
   JButton twoTwobutton = new JButton();
   pane.add(twoTwobutton);
    twoTwobutton.addActionListener(new twoTwoListener());
   twoTwobutton.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 

//2,3
   JButton twoThreebutton = new JButton();
   pane.add(twoThreebutton);
   twoThreebutton.addActionListener(new twoThreeListener());
   twoThreebutton.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 

//3,1
   JButton threeOnebutton = new JButton();
   pane.add(threeOnebutton);
   threeOnebutton.addActionListener(new threeOneListener());
   threeOnebutton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

//3,2
   JButton threeTwobutton = new JButton();
   pane.add(threeTwobutton);
   threeTwobutton.addActionListener(new threeTwoListener());
   threeTwobutton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

//3,3
   JButton threeThreebutton = new JButton();
   pane.add(threeThreebutton);
   threeThreebutton.addActionListener(new threeThreeListener());
   threeThreebutton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


  }
        int turn = 1;


        private class oneOneListener implements ActionListener
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {

                 oneOnebutton.setText("x");




           }
        }

         //******1,2******//
        private class oneTwoListener implements ActionListener
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {





           }
        }



        //******1,3*********//
         private class oneThreeListener implements ActionListener
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {





           }
        }


        //******2,1*********//
         private class twoOneListener implements ActionListener
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {





           }
        }

         //******2,2*********//
         private class twoTwoListener implements ActionListener
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {





           }
        }

        //******2,3*********//
         private class twoThreeListener implements ActionListener
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {





           }
        }

        //******3,1*********//
         private class threeOneListener implements ActionListener
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {





           }
        }


        //******3,2*********//
         private class threeTwoListener implements ActionListener
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {





           }
        }

        //******3,3*********//
         private class threeThreeListener implements ActionListener
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {





           }
        }
   }
```

If you scroll down to action listeners, I have an action listener setup for the button named oneOne (1,1 on the 3x3 grid i have) It gives me an error that says that points to oneOne and says cannot find symbol, what could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oneOnebutton` is defined as a local variable in the `Constructor` of `Dirver`,  you can not access it out of the `Constructor`.

You can make a class member of `Dirver`.

```
public class Driver extends JFrame {
    JButton oneOnebutton;
    ....
}
```

and initiate in the `Constructor`:

```
public Driver() {
    ....
    oneOnebutton = new JButton();
    ....
}
```

this can make sure `oneOnebutton` is available in `oneOneListener`.